# Are `select current_user` and `select current_database()` both SQL query statements?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, we can get the current user and database by

```
select current_user;

select current_database();
```

Is `select` in both statements the same `select` in a SQL query?

Are `current_user` and `current_database()` both column names?

What are the tables they are selected from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- `select` is the very same select as used in any select query
- `current_database()` is a "System Information Function"
- `current_user` is also a "System Information Function"  (see note below)

A function typically takes parameters and therefore are used with parentheses to hold those parameters, but some system functions, such as current_database() don't require any parameters, but the empty parentheses remain.

**System Information Functions** "*extract session and system information*" see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html

> Note
>
> current_catalog, current_role, current_schema, current_user,
>   session_user, and user have special syntactic status in SQL: they must
>   be called without trailing parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. Are returns of current_user and current_database() both column names?

What are the tables they are selected from?

Comment: no, they are not columns in a table, they are functions which return a value

Comment: The term "function" exists in almost any programming language, e.g. both java and javascript have functions. So it isn't necessary for a function to need a table or a column. Another type of function in PostgreSQL is to "concatenate" 2 or more items together and you could use it like this: `select CONCAT('Hello', ' ', 'World')` and that function provides a result of `'Hello World`' i.e. 'Hello world' is "returned" by the function CONCAT() So, these system function current_user "returns" the name of the user who is active in the current session

Comment: if there is no table to select from, what does "select" mean here?

Comment: You are "selecting" the returned value(s) of the system function(s). Basically if you want to display something, you have to start with the term `select`

Comment: Thanks. I see.  Without a table to select from, `select`does not create a new table, correct?  Does SQL standard cover the usage of `select` without a table to select from?

Comment: `select` does not create a table although the columns/rows it displays can be called  a "derived table" - but that isn't a real table. Does the sql standard cover usage without a table?... I believe the answer to that is yes; but not all implementations of SQL follow exactly the same interpretation of the standards. In Oracle for example you must use a table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's been a long while since I read any standard to be honest so I will take your word for it. My "out" is that I said "believe" :) It does seem odd that several implementations ignore that point. *c'est a la vie de SQL*